# htaccess login, is it transported via ssl?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I have a development site locked off with htaccess requiring a user and password authentication prior to being allowed access. The domain itself has a functional ssl certificate installed.

What I am curious about is; How secure is a htaccess login? Does it utilize the ssl? I would assume it does not but would greatly appreciate additional insight into this.

If it does not use ssl, is there a way to force it to do so? Would there be any benefit in doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication (configured via .htaccess or whatever) and use of HTTPS are orthogonal concepts, i.e. you can have HTTPS without authentication and you can have authentication without HTTPS but you can also have both at the same time or none of these.

If you want to be sure that authentication is only done when HTTPS is used then you need to configure your site so that the URL's in question are only available with HTTPS. Enabling authentication will not magically enforce HTTPS. If you only enable authentication but allow access to the URL's with both HTTP and HTTPS then authentication will also be done with both, leading to insecure transfer of passwords if the user stays with plain HTTP.